# Store different object type in one array and print each one with their methods

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, casting

I am trying to create a parent class for cars and subclasses from it. Each one has separate methods and store them in an array then if the class are subclass try to call the method on it.

Parent class

```
public class car {

    public  String name ;
    public double price ;
    
    public car (String name , int price) {
        this.name = name ;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public String  toString() {
        return "car name : "+this.name 
               +" Price : " +this.price ;   
    }   
}
```

Sub class

```
public class CarMotors extends car {

    public float MotorsCapacity ;

    public CarMotors( String name, int price , float MotorsCapacity) {
        super(name, price);
        this.MotorsCapacity = MotorsCapacity ;
    }
    
    public float getMotorsCapacity() {
        return this.MotorsCapacity; 
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        car [] cars = new car[2] ;
        
        cars[0] = new car("M3" , 78000);
        cars[1] = new CarMotors("M4" , 98000 , 3.0f);
        
        for(int i=0 ;i<2;i++){
            if(cars[i] instanceof CarMotors) {
                System.out.println(cars[i].getMotorsCapacity()); // error here
            }else {
                System.out.println(cars[i].toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can't print the getMotorsCapacity(). I am new to Java. I think there is a cast that need to happen, but I don't now how.

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: When posting questions about code that created error messages, it is helpful to include the error messages in the question body, preferably by using copy-and-paste. But, anyway, have you tried `System.out.println(((CarMotors) cars[i]).getMotorsCapacity());` ?

Comment: If you're using a recent Java version, use `if (cars[i] instanceof CarMotors cm) { System.out.println(cm.getMotorsCapacity()); } ...`

Comment: I use version java 18.0.2.1 on my pc but when I work with a university computer I think its an old version so I need a solution for all, Mark Rotteveel solution works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Being short... a class *only can see what its yours* behaviors.

In your example `CarMotors` is a `Car`, that's fine.

But the behavior `getMotorsCapacity()` is created in `CarMotors` and it wasn't in `Car`.

That error occurs because, it's OK in a variable Car you are able to put an instance of `CarMotors` because `CarMotors` is a Car. So, any method that is in Car is also in `CarMotors`, yes, you can call. Look at `cars[i].toString()` there's no problem here.

You need explicitly say to compiler:
"- oh, right, originally this variable is a Car, but I know that is a CarMotors inside that. I will make a cast here, OK compiler? Thanks."

```java
System.out.println(((CarMotors) cars[i]).getMotorsCapacity());
```

Or, to be more clear:

```java
CarMotors carMotors = ((CarMotors) cars[i]); 
System.out.println(carMotors.getMotorsCapacity());
```

Comment: With recent versions of Java, the cast can be done directly in the if: `if (cars[i] instanceof CarMotors carMotors) { /* use carMotors instead of cars[i] */ ... }`

Comment: Can rephrase the first sentence, because _"Being short... a class only can see what its yours behaviors."_ doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe you meant that code can only seen the methods for the declared type of the variable.

Comment: Yes, i'm focus on methods superficially at this moment and i'm not going deep in variables, statics, @override, things like that.

Comment: the solution is working thanks, I just struggling with the concept I read online some solutions but I can get it to work without understanding the concept, but right now I get it thanks again.

Comment: no problem. if my answer helped you to get more understand, please use it in order to close this question. it can be helpful to other people in a similar case as yours. (=